# How to get username with sessions in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session, authentication

I'm making a very simple login autenthication with Codeigniter(3) with two simple fields , username and password.  I'm very new with this and I'm having some problems. This is my controller to verify if the User has entered correct credentials:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class VerifyLogin extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->model('user','',TRUE);
   $this->load->helper('url');

 }

 function index()
 {
   //This method will have the credentials validation
   $this->load->library('form_validation');

   $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|callback_check_database');

   if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
   {
     //Field validation failed.  User redirected to login page
     $this->load->view('login_view');
   }
   else
   {
// session data

      $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
     $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
     $this->load->view('admin/dashboard', $data);

   }

     redirect(site_url('admin/dashboard'), 'refresh');


 }

 function check_database($password)
 {
   //Field validation succeeded.  Validate against database
   $username = $this->input->post('username');

   //query the database
    $result = $this->user->login($username, $password);

   if($result)
   {

     $sess_array = array();
     foreach($result as $row)
     {
       $sess_array = array(
         'id' => $row->id,
         'username' => $row->username
       );

       $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
     }
     return TRUE;
   }
   else
   {
     $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or password');
     return false;
   }
 }
}
?>
```

While the model user.php is this one:

```
function login($username, $password)
 {

$this -> db -> select('id, username, password');
$this -> db -> from('users');
$this -> db -> where('username', $username);
$this -> db -> where('password', $password);
$this -> db -> limit(1);

   $query = $this -> db -> get();

   if($query -> num_rows() == 1)
   {
     return $query->result();
   }
   else
   {
     return false;
   }
 }
```

When in my View I type Welcome `<?php echo $username; ?>` I got undefined variable username. What I'm wrong?

Comment: did u load session lib in autoload??? or forgot?

Comment: No, that's not the problem(unfortunately)

I did like this: `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session');`

Comment: than `print_r($this->session->userdata);` in controller... chk this and share the output

Comment: I got this:

`Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1457637441 [logged_in] => Array ( [id] => 1 [username] => fabio ) )`

Comment: remove redirect(site_url('admin/dashboard'), 'refresh');, answer updated

Answer (score 0):

Your session is working fine as per your comments, you just need to remove redirection, don't know why are you using?

**Remove this line:**

```
redirect(site_url('admin/dashboard'), 'refresh');
```

Comment: Because in the admin controller I retrieve other data that fill me some list, as books, videos, ecc. That's why I use it. Anyway, If i comment that line, the lists cannot be filled, but the username is still not visible.

Comment: @user5913892 than try directly in view `$this->session->userdata('logged_in');`

Comment: If I try to do this `print_r($this->session->userdata('logged_in'));`, I got this [id] => 1 [username] => fabio. But ,if I do `$this->session->userdata('logged_in');` , I do not see anything . I still don't get why.

Comment: `echo $this->session->userdata['logged_in']['username']` @user5913892

Comment: Thank you , now it works. Why I had to do so? Or it's always like this?

Comment: @user5913892 maybe wrong calling. Now if its work plz accept the answer

Comment: OK. It could be better write the right one, in this case someone could use your solution. Then I'll accept your solution